# Display corresponding name based on ID SQL select query

Tags: sql-server, select, subquery

I have 2 tables

tbl_jobs

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_jobs]
(
    [JobID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [JobType] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [RequestID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AssignTo] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FromOrgID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ToOrgID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Ammount] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [JobStatus] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Remark] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [strOwner] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [dbTstamp] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_jobs] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([JobID] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_jobs] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_tbl_jobs_tbl_orgs] 
    FOREIGN KEY([FromOrgID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[tbl_orgs] ([OrgID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_jobs] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_tbl_jobs_tbl_orgs]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_jobs]  WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_tbl_jobs_tbl_orgs1] 
    FOREIGN KEY([ToOrgID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[tbl_orgs] ([OrgID])
GO
```

tbl_orgs

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_orgs]
(
    [OrgID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [OrgName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [OrgTele] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [OrgEmail] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [OrgArea] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [OrgCity] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [OrgLocation] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [OrgType] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [OrgStatus] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [strOwner] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [dbTStamp] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_orgs] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([OrgID] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I need to get most of the `tbl_jobs` columns and corresponding `tbl_orgs.OrgName` for `tbl_jobs.FromOrgID` & `tbl_jobs.ToOrgID`.

If I choose `tbl_orgs.orgname`, I don't get the proper results.

I am stuck here. What type of query should I use to get the result.?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're joining two times to the same table instance. You should click on "add table" and add tbl_orgs one more time and join "FromOrgID" to one instance of it and "ToOrgID" to the other one. Otherwise the join doesn't make sense unless "FromOrgID" and "ToOrgID" are equal.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helped. :)